# Create a product with different colors (associated products) where each color shares stock with all other colors

Tags: product, product-attribute, stock, configurable-product, quantity

Is it possible to create a product with different colors where each different color points to the same stock?

For example, I have created a configurable product with a color attribute. 
After creating the configurable product I create a couple of associated simple products for a few different colors. 
Instead of having each color have it’s own product qty / stock, I want all the colors to share the same stock.

So for example the configurable product is a lamp. The associated simple products are lamp green, lamp red etc. 
I want to tell Magento that the lamp product has 10 in stock. So when someone buys a lamp red, it will tell me there are only 9 lamps left in stock regardless of the color. Is this possible?

The way I have it now is that each associated simple product has it’s own stock, but this is not what I want in my case.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not using custom options?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible out of Magento standard.

You could try to detect a stock change on a child item and then change the stock of all other child items accordingly.

A point to start can be the event `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`.